# When using Sasl.createSaslClient with kerberos, is it possible to modify kerberose configuration options?

Tags: java, security, kerberos, gssapi, jgss

I would like to use non-default location for ticket cache. 
Is it possible to set this value?
I checked [Krb5LoginModule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.html) and it allows for such configuration, but I could not find anything related to Sasl clients.

Any help with this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that if you set KRB5CCNAME environment variable, Kerberos component which SASL client delegates work to, read ticket cache file name/path from this env variable. It resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with the SASL client because SASL is delegating the work to JGSS. What you can you is to obtain a login context with your custom location and perform a `Subject.doAs` with the subject from the login context with the SASL client. This will give you what you want. (Sample code available)